# Captcha for Wordpress customized form

Tags: php, wordpress, content-management-system, captcha

Is there a way to add captcha into a form in wordpress, i have gone through some plugins but it allows only to add captcha in login, comment forms etc..

Comment: but where did you want to add a captcha ?

Comment: i am creating a separate form where i need a captcha before submitting

Comment: a mail to the site owner, with a message

Comment: why you didn't use this plugin : http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/contact-form-7/ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend using [reCAPTCHA](http://www.google.com/recaptcha) it's free, widely use and relatively easy to use.